# Extraer valores de tuplas para formar un pdf con Python

Tags: python, pdf, tuplas

El objetivo del codigo es reorganizar el orden de las paginas de un PDF. Es decir, si tengo un pdf con las paginas (1,2,3,4,5, etc.), quiero generar un pdf que haya reorganizado las paginas a (4,2,1,3,5...) según el orden que establece una tupla (una tupla obtenida de otros procesos). El problema lo tengo en el bucle for que he empleado, porque creo que no estoy dando bien la instrucción. Quiero que coja cada valor de la tupla en ese mismo orden como el numero de pagina que quiero que añada hasta crear el pdf (que sería el mismo que he cargado previamente, pero con el orden de las paginas reordenadas). Aquí muestro el código:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

#Tupla de ejemplo, que viene de la unión de otras tuplas, de ahí ese formato:

Tupla = [((20, 1), (2, 19)), ((18, 3), (4, 17)), ((16, 5), (6, 15)), ((14, 7), (8, 13)), ((12, 9), (10, 11))]

#Imprimo los valores de las tuplas para verlos mejor

for item in resultados:
    print(item[0][0],',',item[0][1],'/',item[1][0],',',item[1][1])


#Ahora cargo el PDF que quiero reorganizar

input_pdf = PdfFileReader("sample.pdf")
output = PdfFileWriter() 

# AQUI ME PIERDO: Y aquí tengo el problema. He puesto un bucle for, en el que quiero que copie cada pagina del pdf formando un pdf nuevo con las paginas en el orden que marca la Tupla

for i in resultados:
            p = input_pdf.getPage(i)
            output.addPage(p)

#Aquí genero el PDF resultante:

with open("documento_creado.pdf", "wb") as f:
        output.write(f)
```

Comment: No entiendo bien ¿Quieres aplanar la tupla `resultado = (20, 1, 2, 19, ..., 11)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te muestro como lo haría, claro que no es la única forma:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

pdf_reader =PdfFileReader("sample.pdf")
output = PdfFileWriter() 

Tupla = [((20, 1), (2, 19)), ((18, 3), (4, 17)), ((16, 5), (6, 15)), ((14, 7), (8, 13)), ((12, 9), (10, 11))]

hojas=[i  for x in Tupla for j in x for i in j]
```

como Tupla es una lista de tuplas la voy a aplanar para que quede solo como una lista

```
for numero_pagina in  hojas:
    temp= pdf_reader.getPage(numero_pagina -1)
    output.addPage(temp)
```

ahora en los numeros de pagina contenidos en la lista leo el número de pagina menos 1 porque lee desde 0 y agregamos la pagina leída

```
with open("documento_creado.pdf", "wb") as f:
        output.write(f)
```

ahora si escribo el resultante

Espero que sea lo que planteaste